# Can I limit Google's app engine Search API to most recent 10,000 items

Tags: google-app-engine, google-search-api

On messaging services like Slack and Ryver they limit the free tier to searching the most recent 10k messages. The next tier up is unlimited search over team messages. I have been unable to find a method in Google's app engine Search API to limit the search to the most recent X thousand items to mimic the behavior of these other messaging services on my platform.

While I am at it I've also been unable to find a way to count how many items are currently stored in a search index.

[notes]
Appengine does support retrieving only from a certain date forward so for now I am using that feature. It would be better to be able to support a recent X messages feature to have parity with Slack and other chat platforms.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do it automatically, but you could add a message number to each document, and add "messageNumber > max - 10000" to the query.

Comment: Since its not easy to support a global changing value in app engine this solution feels unwieldy.